# Screen is not updating when segued from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a view controller (lets call it `AViewController`) which has a background image, buttons, etc. I also have a second view controller (lets call it `BViewController`) with its own set of buttons. *When i transition from one view controller to another, the background image along with the UI Elements of the first view controller is being displayed in the second view controller.* I am using a segue. I faced with problem before. What i did to correct it was change the background colour of the view from white to clear color. But it doesn't not seem to work in this case. (The BViewController contains a UIView in which the user can draw.)

Comment: The view of AViewController shouldn't show up in BViewController, is that what you're saying is happening? How are you doing the transition?

Comment: @rdelmar I have set a background image in AViewController. And i didnt set up 1 in BViewController. However, This image shows up in the second view controller. (It does not refresh)

Comment: Well, it shouldn't show up which is why I asked the question about how you do the transition. How are you doing the transition? Show some code.

Comment: @rdelmar I am using a custom segue. The one that i found here https://github.com/mkftr/DoorwayTransition

Comment: I didn't see that problem with the demo of the segue you linked to, so you're going to have to post your code if you want some help.